# Angular directive within a template

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, templates, angularjs-directive

I am trying to make dynamic loading of directives in my app. I have create a template which looking like this:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="custom-dir">
  <custom-dir component="dir"></custom-dir>
</script>
```

Here is how I load the directives in my main page:

```
<section class="page">
    <section class="main-components">
        <div ng-repeat="dir in directives" ng-include="dir.name"></div>
    </section>
</section>
```

here is the dir object:

```
{
   name: "path_to_dir/custom-dir.html",
   id: "custom-dir"
}
```

Here is the template `path_to_dir/custom-dir.html`:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="root-routing">
  <root-routing component="component"></root-routing>
</script>
```

Here is the directive:

```
  app.directive("rootRouting", [function() {
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      scope: {
        component: "=component"
      },
      replace: true,
      template: "<div></div>",
      link: function($scope, element, $attrs) {
          debugger;
        });
      }
    }
  }]);
```

When I run the app I can see the template in the dom with the directive in it. The problem is that the component logic (under link) never runs. If I put the directive without the template in the main js every thing is working as expected.

What is wrong with my scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/NYEBRhlEtYyqagOixfyB?p=preview)

you are creating template in your template. Change your custom-dir.html to following

```
  <root-routing component="component"></root-routing>
```